# Python Flask and Jinja2 - How to get name of the day from date?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I'm trying to display a name of the day from the date string in Jinja2.

**Example of what I want to achieve:**
From this string: '18-10-2020' - I would get 'Sunday'.

I am looking for a solution that would **not** require me to pass the name of the day from Python to Jinja2, but I would like to get the name of the day completely within Jinja2.

So far, I have the following code in my Jinja2 template:

```
{% for date in list_of_dates %}
    {% set rok, mesiac, den = date[2].split('-') %}
        {{ datetime.datetime.date(rok, mesiac, den).strftime("%A") }}
{% endfor %}
```

This code, however, returns a Jinja2 Exception error saying this: **'datetime' is undefined**. I have datetime imported in my Python code.

Any ideas how can I fix this, please?

Thank you